# Почему segmentation fault то появляется, то исчезает?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Решал такую задачу:
Девочка Грета занимается исследованиями в области глобального потепления. Грета замеряла температуру на улице в течение N дней. Теперь ей интересна следующая статистика: для каждой температуры в интервале [−T;T] узнать номера дней, в которые держалась данная температура.

**Входные данные**
В первой строке входных данных содержатся два натуральных числа: T и N (T≤60, N≤1000). В следующей строке содержатся N целых чисел, по модулю не превосходящих 100 — измерение температуры в каждый из дней. Дни нумеруются с единицы.

**Выходные данные**
Выведите 2T+1 строк. Каждая строка должна содержать данные о днях, в которые держалась данная температура. Используйте формат вывода в соответствии с примером. Температуры необходимо выводить в порядке от меньшей к большей. Дни для каждой температуры необходимо выводить в порядке возрастания.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int t, n;
    cin >> t >> n;
    vector <vector <int> > ans(2*t + 1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        ans[temp + t].push_back(i);
    }
    for (int temp = 0; temp <= 2*t; ++temp) {
        cout << temp - t << ": ";
        for (int j = 0; j < ans[temp].size(); ++j) {
            cout << ans[temp][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что когда я ввожу например:

```
5 10
2 -6 0 4 4 0 -4 -5 -3 2
```

То дальше программа либо выводит результат:

```
-5: 8 
-4: 7 
-3: 9 
-2: 
-1: 
0: 3 6 
1:
2: 1 10 
3: 
4: 4 5 
5:
```

Любо segmentation fault. Из-за чего в данном случае происходит segmentation fault, и почему при одних и тех же входных данных в одних случаях мы получаем ошибку, а в других нет?

Comment: Стоит начать проверять выход за пределы диапазона вектора при обращении к его элементам, а не надеяться на авось. И еще хотя бы попытаться самостоятельно отладить программу.

Comment: А каковы диапазоны вектора? И в моей задаче я вообще ввожу одни и те же числа, но в одних случаях ошибка, а в других нет.

Comment: Окей. В Ваших же входных данных `t` равно 5, а на второй итерации цикла `temp` будет равно -6. И дальше в этом же цикле строка `ans[temp + t]`. Получается, что Вы пытаетесь достучаться до элемента с индексом -1. Вот Вам и segmentation fault.

Comment: Считывайте не просто температуру, а вносите ее в `pair<int,int>`, где вторым полем - номер дня. Сортируйте по первому полю, выводите. Все предельно просто. А, да! почему проблемы у вас? Ну, например, T = 5, а температура -10. В какой элемент вы записываете номер дня? С отрицательным индексом, правда? Ну и к чему это приводит?

Comment: Допустимый диапазон при обращении к элементам вектора определяется количеством хранящихся в нем элементов (`size()`). Можно обращаться к элементам с индексами от 0 до size() - 1.

Comment: @Harry from Kiev,  да, это приведет к segmentation fault, вообщем-то и приводит, но не всегда... Вот к примеру беру я входные данные, что выше. И когда я ввожу температуру -6, то у меня программа должна сразу выдавать segmentation fault, но нет, бывает так, что "проскакивает", т.е компилятор просто пропускает это значение температуры, так как не находит, соответствия с номером в массиве. А затем программа выводит результат, без всяких ошибок. И я вот никак не могу понять, как так получается, ведь по логике такого происходить не должно. Как в таком случае компилятор всё это обрабатывает?

Comment: Компилятору это все по барабану, он не проверяет, куда вы там пишете - ведь это будет происходить во время работы, а не при компиляции. Дополнительный же код для проверки выхода за пределы массива компилятор тоже не добавляет, так как это бы очень тормозило работу программы. К конкретно вашей задаче - идея у вас в принципе понятна, только брать надо размер не 2t+1, а такой, чтоб в него поместились все температуры - от -100 до 100, т.е. 201. И работать с ним с соответствующим пересчетом. Понятно, как, или надо написать?

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, “Компилятору это все по барабану, он не проверяет, куда вы там пишете - ведь это будет происходить во время работы, а не при компиляции.” Хорошо, но всё равно не понимаю, ведь иногда ошибка появляется. Как написать программу понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*нужно создать вектор который в свою очередь состоит из векторов произвольной длины(температура и произвольное количество дней, в которые была данная температура). И сделать это нужно пользуясь минимумом инструментов, т.е самим вектором и циклом for, не прибегая к использованию вектора собственной структура и контейнеру map.*
Тогда так: первый вектор будет из 201 элемента vector <vector  > ans(201) - температура от -100 до 100 и плюс 0. А в конечных векторах - номера дней. Тогда чтобы обращаться по температуре как по индексу нужно добавлять к температуре 100 - тогда в ans[0] будет храниться массив дней для температуры -100, в ans[100] - для температуры 0, в ans[200] для температуры +100:

```
vector <vector <int> > ans(201);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) 
{
   int temp;
   cin >> temp;
   ans[temp + 100].push_back(i);
}
```

И всё-таки проверяйте вводимые значения на корректность условиям задачи. Т.е. вводимые температуры должны лежать в диапазоне -100 < temp < +100. Иначе т.к. значение температуры используется как индекс, при некорректном вводе всё равно будет выход за границы массива и неопределенное поведение программы.

Answer (score 0):

Вы видимо хотели иметь вектор, в котором будет вектор из 2 значений - номер дня и температура в этот день. Тогда вы немного неправильно вносите данные, должно быть вот так:

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) 
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        ans.push_back({ i, temp});
    }
```

Но как написал @Harry from Kiev в данном случае лучше использовать вектор пар, или вектор собственной структуры из 2 элементов.

```
struct Day
{ int day;
  int temp;
}
vector<Day> ans(2*t + 1);
// или
vector< pair<int,int> > ans(2*t + 1);
```

Если дальше смотреть условия вашей задачи, то болеее оптимальным будет использование вместо vector<> контейнера map<> (или multimap<>, если температура может повторяться), который хранит пары из ключа и значения. Тогда ключом будет температура, а значением - номер дня. В этом случае и сортировка сразу происходит - в map<> данные хранятся в отсортированном виде.

```
map<int,int> ans;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) 
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        ans[temp] = i; // если элемента с таким ключом нет, то он вставляется
    }
```

Comment: "Вы видимо хотели иметь вектор, в котором будет вектор из 2 значений - номер дня и температура в этот день."  Не совсем так, нужно создать вектор который в свою очередь состоит из векторов произвольной длины(температура и произвольное количество дней, в которые была данная температура). И сделать это нужно пользуясь минимумом инструментов, т.е самим вектором и циклом for, не прибегая к использованию вектора собственной структура и контейнеру map.

Comment: @Ateus Опишите как вы собираетесь хранить данные? По сути вы пытаетесь написать свой multimap.

Comment: да, можно и так сказать. Просто это задача была дана в контексте прохождения двумерных массивов.